# Why do I get a "The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once" when I get the Count() before enumerating the result?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

This my code. Simplified for readability

```
var query = from p in people select p;

// here is the point that probably causes the issue
ObjectResult<int> idsThatMatch = getIdsThatMatchFullTextSearch("andre");
query = from p in query where idsThatMatch.Contains(p.id) select p;

var count = query.Count();
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.id);
var pessoas = query.Skip(90).Take(30).ToList();
```

I need to read the count before skip/take to get the total amount of records before paging. The count works fine. But at the last line of my excerpt it triggers the exception

> The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Why? The count isn't supposed to enumerate anything by the way. And how can I solve that? Thank you

**EDIT**

People thought I was using stored procedures but I'm not. Actually I'm using a "select in". The code is bellow the comment.

**EDIT 2**

I just tested the above code without the "select in" part and it works fine

**EDIT 3**

Using this line works:

```
ObjectResult<int> idsThatMatch = (getIdsThatMatchFullTextSearch("andre");
query = from p in query where idsThatMatch.Contains(p.id) select p).ToArray();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
ObjectResult<int> idsThatMatch = getIdsThatMatchFullTextSearch("andre");
```

This returns `ObjectResult` not `ObjectQuery` or `IQueryable`. Result can be iterated only once. Once you execute your first query with `Count` you cannot use result anymore and your second query execution will fail because it will try to iterate result again.

`ObjectResult` is not processed on database side - it is the result of executed `ObjectQuery` and one execution can have only one enumeration of result set. It is like cursor to iterate through result set in your application.

Comment: I modified it (EDIT 3) so that the result of idsThatMatch is cached in an array before my next operations. Thank you very much. (you already helped my a lot of times)

Answer (score 1):

Your people may be coming from a stored procedure mapped in Entity Framework model.
In that case you can not do filtering or skipping on it since the result has already been evaluated.

[The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once)

[The query results cannot be enumerated more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361237/the-query-results-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once)

Comment: no no.. there is no stored procedure involved. And I've seen these links before. They didn't help much =/ thank you anyway

Comment: @AndréPena people can not be hanging in the air. Please share where the people is coming from? What does the actual query really look like.

Comment: I'll share it.. just a moment